# Illegal Argument Exception: Given String is empty or null

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a firebase project and getting this error

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.root.firebase/com.root.firebase.MainActivity}:
>   java. lang. Illegal Argument Exception: Given String is empty or null

My code line of error is:

```
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

    @Override

    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

    if (task.isSuccessful()) 
    {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else 
    {                
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Could not Register... Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check if your email or password is not null

Comment: it gives me error before showing the email and password layout

Comment: you didn't added your activity in manifest i guess please check it once, if its declared

Comment: found the error; was overriding that method outside register button; thanks

Comment: can you share your code from where you are starting Activity